# Recursive methods to create Streams in Scala

Tags: scala, stream, fibonacci

This is a follow-up to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659127/how-to-fix-my-fibonacci-stream-in-scala).

As I [understand](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8659299/650444) the following method for calculating Fibonacci numbers is inefficient since the method `fib` is called for each Fibonacci number and each time it is called it creates a new stream.

```
def fib:Stream[Int] =
  Stream.cons(1, Stream.cons(1, (fib zip fib.tail) map {case (x, y) => x + y}))
```

On other hand the *tail recursive* method (as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659127/how-to-fix-my-fibonacci-stream-in-scala/8659691#8659691)) looks quite efficient and calculates each Fibonacci number in `O(1)`

```
def fib(a:Int, b:Int):Stream[Int] = Stream.cons(a, fib(b, a+b));
```

Now I am concluding that recursive methods that create Streams are efficient *if and only if* they are tail recursive. Is it correct?

Comment: Neither example is tail recursive.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral Could you explain why the 2nd implementation calculates each Fibonacci number in `O(1)` but the 1st one does it in `O(N)`

Comment: Oops sorry... I was talking about the first... Let me remove my comment...

Comment: Andy has answered it, but I'll try to give a more illustrative example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've tried to improve on [Andy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/193246/andy-petrella)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8714442/53013), but he pretty much nailed it. The first solution is creating a pyramid of streams -- each call to `fib` creates *another* fibonacci stream, and each of these new streams will create new stream themselves, and so on.

To be clear, there are *three* streams resulting from a call to `fib`:

- One created by `fib` in `fib zip fib.tail`
- One created by `fib.tail` in `fib zip fib.tail`
- One created by `map` (remember, `map` creates a new collection)

Since the first two are calls to `fib`, they'll create three streams each, and so on.

Here's a rough "picture" of it:

```
                          1
                          1
          1               2               1
          1               3       1       2       1
    1     2       1       5       1       3   1   2   1
    1     3   1   2   1   8   1   2   1   5   1   3 1 2 1
```

And this goes on and on. The middle stream is computed using the highest streams to its left and right (fib and fib.tail). Each of them is computed using lower streams on *their* left and right. Each of these lower streams is computed using streams shown on the last line.

We could continue this on and on, but you can see that, by the time we computed 8, we already have 14 other fibonacci streams going on.

If you change it from `def` to `val`, all these new streams disappear, because `fib` and `fib.tail` will refer to an *existing* stream instead of creating new streams. And since no new stream will be created, there will be no further calls to `fib` and `fib.tail`.

Now, if you look at the second answer, you'll notice that there is a single `fib` call, and no `map` or similar method, so there's no multiplication effect.

Answer (score 7):

No, tail recursive is to help the compiler looping instead of stacking (globally), it's a compile time optimization.

The problem came from the first implementation where several calls to `fib` leads to several Stream constructions, so the same calculus are made over and over.

```
fib zip fib.tail
//if we are at the 1000, it will compute million Streams
```

If you want to see it try the following

```
var i = 0
def fib:Stream[Int] = {
  i = i + 1
  println("new Stream : " + i)
  Stream.cons(1, Stream.cons(1, (fib zip fib.tail) map {case (x, y) => x + y}))
}
```