# Is there any advantage to definining a val over a def in a trait?

Tags: scala, compiler-optimization, traits

In Scala, a `val` can override a `def`,  but a `def` cannot override a `val`.

So, is there an advantage to declaring a trait e.g. like this:

```
trait Resource {
  val id: String
}
```

rather than this?

```
trait Resource {
  def id: String
}
```

The follow-up question is: how does the compiler treat **calling** `val`s and `def`s differently in practice and what kind of optimizations does it actually do with `val`s? The compiler insists on the fact that `val`s are stable — what does in mean in practice for the compiler? Suppose the subclass is actually implementing `id` with a `val`. Is there a penalty for having it specified as a `def` in the trait?

If my code itself does not require stability of the `id` member, can it be considered good practice to always use `def`s in these cases and to switch to `val`s only when a performance bottleneck has been identified here — however unlikely this may be?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Short answer:**

As far as I can tell, the values are always accessed through the accessor method. Using `def` defines a simple method, which returns the value. Using `val` defines a **private [*]** final field, with an accessor method. So in terms of access, there is very little difference between the two. The difference is conceptual, `def` gets reevaluated each time, and `val` is only evaluated once. This can obviously have an impact on performance.

[*] Java private

**Long answer:**

Let's take the following example:

```
trait ResourceDef {
  def id: String = "5"
}

trait ResourceVal {
  val id: String = "5"
}
```

The `ResourceDef` & `ResourceVal` produce the same code, ignoring initializers:

```
public interface ResourceVal extends ScalaObject {
    volatile void foo$ResourceVal$_setter_$id_$eq(String s);
    String id();
}

public interface ResourceDef extends ScalaObject {
    String id();
}
```

For the subsidiary classes produced (which contain the implementation of the methods), the `ResourceDef` produces is as you would expect, noting that the method is static:

```
public abstract class ResourceDef$class {
    public static String id(ResourceDef $this) {
        return "5";
    }

    public static void $init$(ResourceDef resourcedef) {}
}
```

and for the val, we simply call the initialiser in the containing class

```
public abstract class ResourceVal$class {
    public static void $init$(ResourceVal $this) {
        $this.foo$ResourceVal$_setter_$id_$eq("5");
    }
}
```

When we start extending:

```
class ResourceDefClass extends ResourceDef {
  override def id: String = "6"
}

class ResourceValClass extends ResourceVal {
  override val id: String = "6"
  def foobar() = id
}

class ResourceNoneClass extends ResourceDef
```

Where we override, we get a method in the class which just does what you expect. The def is simple method:

```
public class ResourceDefClass implements ResourceDef, ScalaObject {
    public String id() {
        return "6";
    }
}
```

and the val defines a private field and accessor method:

```
public class ResourceValClass implements ResourceVal, ScalaObject {
    public String id() {
        return id;
    }

    private final String id = "6";

    public String foobar() {
        return id();
    }
}
```

Note that even `foobar()` doesn't use the field `id`, but uses the accessor method.

And finally, if we don't override, then we get a method which calls the static method in the trait auxiliary class:

```
public class ResourceNoneClass implements ResourceDef, ScalaObject {
    public volatile String id() {
        return ResourceDef$class.id(this);
    }
}
```

I've cut out the constructors in these examples.

So, the accessor method is always used. I assume this is to avoid complications when extending multiple traits which could implement the same methods. It gets complicated really quickly.

**Even longer answer:**

Josh Suereth did a very interesting talk on [Binary Resilience at Scala Days 2012](http://skillsmatter.com/podcast/scala/binary-resilience), which covers the background to this question. The abstract for this is:

> This talk focuses on binary compatibility on the JVM and what it means
>   to be binary compatible. An outline of the machinations of binary
>   *incompatibility* in Scala are described in depth, followed by a set of rules and guidelines that will help developers ensure their own
>   library releases are both binary compatible and binary *resilient*.
>
> In particular, this talk looks at:
>
> - Traits and binary compatibility
> - Java Serialization and anonymous classes
> - The hidden creations of lazy vals
> - Developing code that is binary resilient

Comment: Your answer doesn't directly address the final part of the question, as to whether there is really any particular reason to choose val over def given that the two behave very similarly once compiled. To me, it would seem that the only reason to choose val having read your answer is for documentation purposes - making it clear that a val field never changes, while a def is less specified in this regard.

Comment: Very nice answer, Matthew, thanks. So the compiler doesn't really use the "stable" information when it's accessing the members, then? I.e., something like `if (res.id.size > 1) res.id.substring(0, 1) else ""` will generate two calls to the `id()` method, no matter if it is a `val` or a `def`?

Comment: @iainmcgin They behave similarly in the examples that I give, but if the initialisation is more complex, then obviously the situation changes, because the def is potentially called more than once.

Comment: @Jean-PhilippePellet It does indeed id + id in foobar() above becomes (new StringBuilder()).append(id()).append(id()).toString()

Answer (score 2):

The difference is mainly that you can implement/override a def with a val but not the other way around. Moreover val are evaluated only once and def are evaluated every time they are used, using def in the abstract definition will give the code who mixes the trait more freedom about how to handle and/or optimize the implementation. So my point is use defs whenever there isn't a clear good reason to force a val.

Comment: I know that using `def`s give more freedom to the implementer. The question is about what kind of optimizations the compiler does when it accesses a stable member (like a val) and what the implied cost is of defining everything with `def`s.

Answer (score 0):

A `val` expression is evaluated once on variable declaration, it is strict and immutable.

A `def` is re-evaluated each time you call it

Comment: The question about *trait* context, so there is something more than this

Comment: I'm not asking about the difference between `def id = "id"` and `val id = "id"`. I'm asking about what kind of optimizations the compiler does when it knows it accesses a stable member (like a `val`) and what it implies in member declarations for traits.

Answer (score -2):

`def` is evaluated by name and `val` by value. This means more or less that `val` must always return an actual value, while `def` is more like a promess that you can get a value when evaluating it. For example, if you have a function

```
def trace(s: => String ) { if (level == "trace") println s } // note the => in parameter definition
```

that logs an event only if the log level is set to trace and you want to log an objects `toString`. If you have overriden `toString` with a value, then you need to pass that value to the `trace` function. If `toString` however is a `def`, it will only be evaluated once it's sure that the log level is trace, which could save you some overhead.
 `def` gives you more flexibility, while `val` is potentially faster

Compilerwise, `traits` are compiled to java interfaces so when defining a member on a `trait`, it makes no difference if its a `var` or `def`. The difference in performance would depend on how you choose to implement it.

Comment: This is disconnected from the call-by-name vs. call-by-value argument passing style. I'm interested about the performance implications of defining everything as a `def` in a trait (given the subclass actually implement it with a `val`).

Comment: Well, if you check the last part of the answer, you'll see the explanation that traits are compiled to java interfaces , meaning it doesn't matter if you define them as `def` or `var` on the `trait`, only the implementation matters. Make the try compiling an example of both and then check them the .class with `javap`.