# Does scala have delayed definition constants?

Tags: scala

If Java I could legally do this...

```
int num = 5;
final boolean isPositive;
if(five > 0) {
  isPositive = true;
} else {
  isPositive = false;
}
System.out.println("Is positive: " + isPositive); // Prints "Is positive: true"
```

I call these delayed definition constants.

Is there a way to create delayed definition constants in Scala?

Comment: AFAIK you can't do that in Scala; but one could use [lazy vals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449474/def-vs-val-vs-lazy-val-evaluation-in-scala) in a similar way.

Comment: `lazy val` isn't relevant here IMO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In scala you can't delay the definition. If you wanted to do something similar then you would typically achieve this by assigning it to the result of the if statement.

```
val isPositive = if(num > 0) true else false
```

or even just

```
val isPositive = num > 0
```

Comment: Maybe worth adding that Java semantics of if statements and closing over values requires the Java idiom. And that final and constant are different concepts.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
val isPositive = num > 0
```

or (when `num` is hard to compute and might not be called - then you can delay computation)

```
lazy val isPositive = num > 0
```

if the `num` is a variable then you can write:

```
def isPositive = num > 0
```

In Scala it's perfectly OK to write short functions as one liners.

Answer (score 1):

I did it like this...

```
val num = 5
val isPositive: Boolean = {
  if(num > 0) { true }
  else { false }
}
println("Is positive: " + isPositive) // Prints "Is positive: true"
```