# Scala: if a client val is lazy, but if it's not called, and .close() is executed, will it throw an error?

Tags: scala

If a client `val` is `lazy`, but it's not called, and `.close()` is executed, will it throw an error?
Example:

```
private lazy val cloudWatchClient = CloudWatchClient.builder.region(region).build
```

`cloudWatchClient` isn't called.

Later, we'll attempt to close it

```
try {
cloudWatchClient.close()
}
```

Does this mean the `cloudWatchClient` client will open and then closed every time if it's not called at line `cloudWatchClient.close()`?

Comment: Yes it will be initialized and closed immediately.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez then `lazy` isn't needed since `cloudWatchClient.close()` will be executed. Thanks, I'm wondering why the other dev at my work is insisting on adding `lazy` hmm

Comment: @sojim2 it doesn't mean that `lazy` is not neede, it means that the whole variable is not needed when it's not used!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it will not throw an error (unless you implemented `CloudWatchClient` to do that on purpose when being initialized). When you prefix a `val` definition with a `lazy` modifier, the initializing expression on the right-hand side will only be evaluated the first time the `val` is used.

Here's a nice example that shows the difference. First a normal object:

```
scala> object SomeObj {
         val x = {
           println("initializing x")
           "done"
         }
       }
defined object SomeObj

scala> SomeObj
initializing x
val res0: SomeObj.type = SomeObj$@7c3c3d67

scala> SomeObj.x
val res1: String = done
```

Now an object containing a `lazy val`:

```
scala> object SomeLazyObj {
         lazy val x = {
           println("initializing lazy x")
           "done"
         }
       }
defined object SomeLazyObj


scala> SomeLazyObj
val res2: SomeLazyObj.type = SomeLazyObj$@3e4636c3

scala> SomeLazyObj.x
initializing lazy x
val res3: String = done
```

You can probably now figure that intuitively what `lazy` does in your example is to avoid initializing `cloudWatchClient` on the spot. In fact, its initialization happens exactly before `close()` is called, since operands are evaluated left-to-right, and the method `close()` needs `cloudWatchClient` initialized before it can itself be called.

It is worth noting that unlike a `def`, a `lazy val` is never evaluated more than once. After the first evaluation of the `lazy val`, the result is stored, to be reused when the same `val` is used subsequently.

However, [there is one trick to it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9450146/2205089): if during the first evaluation of your `lazy val` you get an `Exception`, the next time you will try to access the `lazy val`, it will try to re-evaluate itself.