# Can I extend an existing class (e.g. String) with a custom trait in Scala?

Tags: scala, polymorphism, traits

Consider the simple trait `TypeName`

```scala
trait TypeName {
    def typeName(): String
}
```

For a custom class, it is clear how I might specify my implementation for the `typeName` method.

```scala
class Point(val x: Int, val y: Int) extends TypeName {
    def typeName(): String = {
        "Point"
    }   
}
```

This now allows me to write a function like this

```scala
def printlnTypeName[T <: TypeName](value: T) = {
    println(value.typeName());
}
```

However, if I would like to give a standard library class this functionality. So that I might be able to pass a `String`, `Vector` or `Array` to this `printlnTypeName` function and print their type name!

How might I do this?

Comment: Using a typeclass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- OOP way would be to introduce wrappers for standard-library classes and make them extend the trait

```scala
trait TypeName {
  def typeName(): String
}

class Point(val x: Int, val y: Int) extends TypeName {
  override def typeName(): String = "Point"
}

class StringHolder(value: String) extends TypeName {
  override def typeName(): String = "String"
}

class VectorHolder[A](value: Vector[A]) extends TypeName {
  override def typeName(): String = "Vector"
}

// class VectorHolder[A <: TypeName](value: Vector[A]) extends TypeName {
//   override def typeName(): String = s"Vector[${value.head.typeName()}]"
// }

class ArrayHolder[A](value: Array[A]) extends TypeName {
  override def typeName(): String = "Array"
}

def printlnTypeName[T <: TypeName](value: T) =
  println(value.typeName())
```

- FP way would be to introduce a type class (this is a more flexible approach)

```scala
// type class
trait TypeName[A] {
  def typeName(): String
}
object TypeName {
  // instances

  implicit val stringTypeName: TypeName[String] = () => "String"

  implicit def vectorTypeName[A](implicit
    aTypeName: TypeName[A]
  ): TypeName[Vector[A]] = () => s"Vector[${aTypeName.typeName()}]"

  implicit def arrayTypeName[A](implicit
    aTypeName: TypeName[A]
  ): TypeName[Array[A]] = () => s"Array[${aTypeName.typeName()}]"
}

class Point(val x: Int, val y: Int)
object Point {
  implicit val pointTypeName: TypeName[Point] = () => "Point"
}

def printlnTypeName[T](value: T)(implicit tTypeName: TypeName[T]) =
  println(tTypeName.typeName())
```

Some intros to type classes:

https://kubuszok.com/2018/implicits-type-classes-and-extension-methods-part-1/

https://tpolecat.github.io/2013/10/12/typeclass.html https://tpolecat.github.io/2015/04/29/f-bounds.html

https://books.underscore.io/shapeless-guide/shapeless-guide.html#sec:generic:type-classes (chapter 3.1)

https://www.baeldung.com/scala/type-classes

https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/book/types-type-classes.html

https://gist.github.com/BalmungSan/c19557030181c0dc36533f3de7d7abf4#typeclasses

- You can use already existing type classes:

```scala
// libraryDependencies += scalaOrganization.value % "scala-reflect" % scalaVersion.value
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.{TypeTag, typeOf}

def printlnTypeName[T: TypeTag](value: T) =
  println(typeOf[T])
```

or

```scala
// libraryDependencies += "com.chuusai" %% "shapeless" % "2.3.10"
import shapeless.Typeable

def printlnTypeName[T: Typeable](value: T) =
  println(Typeable[T].describe)
```

(`def foo[T: TC](value: T)` is a syntax sugar for `def foo[T](value: T)(implicit tc: TC[T])`)

Comment: What is the benefit of writing `stringTypeName` as
`implicit val stringTypeName: TypeName[String] = () => "String"`, as opposed to `implicit def ...`

Comment: @doliphin an `implicit def` would create a new instance on each invocation... just like a `def` VS a `val`. `implicit def` are used when you need derivation like `implicit def typeableList[A](implicit ev: Typeable[A]): Typeable[List[A]]`; otherwise is better to just use `implicit val` to cache the instances.

Comment: @doliphin https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449474/def-vs-val-vs-lazy-val-evaluation-in-scala