# why use def and val in Scala or vice versa

Tags: scala

I know this has been discussed on SO in other posts before and I understand the basic difference between the use of `def` and `val`. `def` is used for defining a method and `val` for an immutable reference. What I am trying to accomplish by asking this question is to understand if there is something more to `def`. Can it be used interchangeably with a `val`?

Recently I tried the following code and cannot convince myself if my present understanding of `def` is sufficient:

```
scala> def i: Int = 3
i: Int

scala> i
res2: Int = 3
```

So I am curious, is this equivalent to `val i = 3`?

Then I tried this:

```
scala> i()
<console>:9: error: Int does not take parameters
i()
```

I did this just to test my understanding of the semantics of `def`. Now I want to know, when `i` is a method, why Scala complains with "...does not take parameters"?

Next I tried the following:

```
scala> def i(): Int = 3
i: ()Int

scala> i()
res4: Int = 3
```

This time Scala seems to agree that `i` is a method. So can I use `def` in place of `val` interchangeable to declare and initialize a variable?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both

```
def i = 3
```

and

```
def i() = 3
```

declare methods. The only difference is, that the first one is a method without a parameter list and the second is a method with an empty parameter list. The former is usually used for methods without side effects and the latter for methods with side effects.
You should use a val instead of a def if the value never changes and you want to avoid recomputing it. A def gets recomputed every time it is called, while a val is assigned a value only once.

Comment: Just to re-iterate, you can use either parens or no parens for any method that takes no parameters, using parens for methods with side effects is "only" convention, but I highly suggest you follow it. But the compiler won't stop you if you're doing something like `def dontDoThis = println("Hi!")`

Comment: Right answers. So extending this logic, I can say val list = List(1,2,3) and then I can call list.size() or list.length(). Both are methods without side effects, right? So I can also call them in this way: list.size or list.length

Comment: You can call a method that is declared with `()` without the parentheses, but you can't call a method that is declared without parentheses with parentheses.

Comment: I see. Subtle and makes sense.

Comment: Just for reference: you can define method with any number of empty parameter lists:`def i()()() = 3`.

Comment: @incrop, that is interesting. What is a use case for a method with any number of empty parameter lists?

Comment: Then you can only partialy apply function. Doesn't make sence with zero number of parameters.

Comment: @ilango it also might have uses for machine-generated code, so you can avoid special cases.  ("This generated method called _someMethod(...)(...)(...)_ always has three parameter lists.  They just might be empty.")

Answer (score 7):

`def` defines a method, `val` defines an immutable value, as you already know.

One major difference is in when the expression on the right side of the `=` is evaluated. For a method, it is evaluated each time you call the method. For a value, it is evaluated when you initialize the value. See the difference:

```
scala> def i: Int = { println("Hello"); 3 }
i: Int

scala> i
Hello
res0: Int = 3

scala> i
Hello
res1: Int = 3

scala> val i: Int = { println("Hello"); 3 }
Hello
i: Int = 3

scala> i
res2: Int = 3
```

Comment: Just read your comment after taking a break from SOF. Very useful input.Good answer.

Comment: See also my answer on the difference between `def`, `val` and `var` here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437373/use-of-def-val-and-var-in-scala/4440614#4440614

Answer (score 6):

Just to add on the top of the Kim's answer, you can override def by val.

```
// Entering paste mode (Ctrl+D to finish)

trait A {
  def i: Int
  def num: Long
}

class B extends A {
  val i = 7
  val num = 20L
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined trait A
defined class B

scala> val b = new B
b: B = B@2d62bdd8

scala> b.i
res1: Int = 7

scala> b.num
res2: Long = 20
```

Comment: The possibilities in Scala! Overriding def by val. I did not know that.