# Scala: How to modify some variable in class by method?

Tags: class, scala, var

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use of def, val, and var in scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437373/use-of-def-val-and-var-in-scala)

I'm learning now Scala and I can't modify variable in class.

```scala
class Person(name: String, var variable: Int) {
  def change() {
    variable = 42
  }
}
def person = new Person("name", 0)
println(person.variable)
person.change()
println(person.variable)
```

And the output is:

```
0
0
```

Why output contains 2 times 0?

How I can modify variable in this Code?

I have Scala version 2.9.1.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437373/use-of-def-val-and-var-in-scala/4440614

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This took me a while to realize as well :)

You are not defining a `val` or `var` "person", but creating a new *method* `person`. Therefore, every time you you invoke `person`, it will create a new instance of `Person`, which will always have its `variable` set to `0`. This is a side effect of the fact that in Scala you don't need the `()` to invoke parameterless methods.

```
def person = new Person("foo", 1)
```

is roughly equivalent to (in Java code)

```
public Person person() {
    return new Person("foo", 1);
}
```

whereas `val person` is what you want, i.e.

```
Person person = new Person("foo", 1)
```

(of course that is not a real `val` because Scala does not support those :))

and when you then use `person`, what Scala understands is `person()`.

Just change `def`, which is used for defining methods, to `val` or `var` and you'll be fine :)

Answer (score 6):

Wasn't easy to spot! Here:

```
def person = new Person("name", 0)
```

you define a method named `person`. To make it more clear, you do something like this:

```
def person(): Person = {
  return new Person("name", 0)
}
```

That means every time you say `person` you are not referring to a variable but calling a method and creating new instance over and over again.

Just say `val person =`... and you'll be fine.

Believe it or not, that's actually a feature of the language. E.g. you can create a field (`val`) in your class, then change your mind and turn it into a getter by simply changing to `def`. From the client code perspective nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

Let's analyze your code, piece by piece.
First you declared a class called person.
`class Person(name: String, var variable: Int)`
with 2 parameters, name and variable.
Under this class, you have a method called: `def change()`.

and it has a variable with 42 as its value.
Then you called the `def change()` method by `person.change()`

This `person.change()` is not actually changing the value of the var `variable` but is actually calling the method it self.
Try doing a `println(person.change())` and you will see that it will print "42".

I guess, you still don't understand the difference between class and def.
if you want to change the value of `class Person`, you need a new def to call the change.

```
 class Person(name: String, var variable: Int) {
  println(variable)
}
def changePerson = Person("new value of name here", "new value of variable here");
```

Now call the `defChangePerson` and it will now print the value you passed to it.