# Filter Method in searchView Widget for android scala eclipse plugin

Tags: java, android, eclipse, scala

I used searchView widget in android, eclipse Scala plugin, I want to update my List after pressing the search button, right-now I have some error in my filter method implementation

would you please give me some hints,

Here is the Filter Method:

```
 override def getFilter(): Filter = {
  new Filter() {

    protected override def publishResults(constraint: CharSequence, results: 
FilterResults) {
      books = results.values.asInstanceOf[List[BookMetadata]]
      ItemAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    protected override def performFiltering(constraint: CharSequence): FilterResults = {
      val filteredResults: List[BookMetadata] =   
 ListBuffer(books.asScala.toList.filter(b.startsWith(constraint.toString)): _*)
      val results = new FilterResults()
      results.values = filteredResults
      results
    }
  }
}
```

I have an error here :

books = results.values.asInstanceOf[List[BookMetadata]]

```
 error: Multiple markers at this 
line 
- reassignment to val 
- reassignment to val
```

one error for b.
     val filteredResults: List[BookMetadata] =
      ListBuffer(books.asScala.toList.filter(b.startsWith(constraint.toString)): _*)

```
  not found: value 
  b
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change from

```
val books
```

to

```
var books
```

And
change

```
val filteredResults: List[BookMetadata] = ListBuffer(books.asScala.toList.filter(b.startsWith(constraint.toString)): _*)
```

to

```
val filteredResults: List[BookMetadata] = ListBuffer(books.asScala.toList.filter(b => b.startsWith(constraint.toString)): _*)
```

And please see [Use of def, val, and var in scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437373/use-of-def-val-and-var-in-scala)