# What is the difference between "def" and "val" to define a function

Tags: scala

What is the difference between:

```
def even: Int => Boolean = _ % 2 == 0
```

and

```
val even: Int => Boolean = _ % 2 == 0
```

Both can be called like `even(10)`.

Comment: Hi, what does `Int => Boolean` means? I think the define syntax is `def foo(bar: Baz): Bin = expr`

Comment: @Ziu that means that the function 'even' receives an Int as an argument and returns a Boolean as a value type. So you can call 'even(3)' which evaluates to Boolean 'false'

Comment: @DenysLobur thanks for your reply! Any reference about this syntax?

Comment: @Ziu I basically found it out from Odersky's Coursera course - https://www.coursera.org/learn/progfun1. By the time you finish it, you'll understand what 'Type => Type' means

Answer (score 359, accepted):

Method `def even` evaluates on call and creates new function every time (new instance of `Function1`).

```
def even: Int => Boolean = _ % 2 == 0
even eq even
//Boolean = false

val even: Int => Boolean = _ % 2 == 0
even eq even
//Boolean = true
```

With `def` you can get new function on every call:

```
val test: () => Int = {
  val r = util.Random.nextInt
  () => r
}

test()
// Int = -1049057402
test()
// Int = -1049057402 - same result

def test: () => Int = {
  val r = util.Random.nextInt
  () => r
}

test()
// Int = -240885810
test()
// Int = -1002157461 - new result
```

`val` evaluates when defined, `def` - when called:

```
scala> val even: Int => Boolean = ???
scala.NotImplementedError: an implementation is missing

scala> def even: Int => Boolean = ???
even: Int => Boolean

scala> even
scala.NotImplementedError: an implementation is missing
```

Note that there is a third option: `lazy val`.

It evaluates when called the first time:

```
scala> lazy val even: Int => Boolean = ???
even: Int => Boolean = <lazy>

scala> even
scala.NotImplementedError: an implementation is missing
```

But returns the same result (in this case same instance of `FunctionN`) every time:

```
lazy val even: Int => Boolean = _ % 2 == 0
even eq even
//Boolean = true

lazy val test: () => Int = {
  val r = util.Random.nextInt
  () => r
}

test()
// Int = -1068569869
test()
// Int = -1068569869 - same result
```

**Performance**

`val` evaluates when defined.

`def` evaluates on every call, so performance could be worse than `val` for multiple calls. You'll get the same performance with a single call. And with no calls you'll get no overhead from `def`, so you can define it even if you will not use it in some branches.

With a `lazy val` you'll get a lazy evaluation: you can define it even if you will not use it in some branches, and it evaluates once or never, but you'll get a little overhead from double check locking on every access to your `lazy val`.

As @SargeBorsch noted you could define method, and this is the fastest option:

```
def even(i: Int): Boolean = i % 2 == 0
```

But if you need a function (not method) for function composition or for higher order functions (like `filter(even)`) compiler will generate a function from your method every time you are using it as function, so performance could be slightly worse than with `val`.

With java 8+ lambda optimisations converting method to function is a cheap operation.

Comment: Would you please compare them regarding the performance? Isn't it important to evaluate the function each time `even` is called.

Comment: `def` can be used to define a method, and this is fastest option. @A.Karimi

Comment: For fun: on 2.12, `even eq even`.

Comment: Is there a concept of inline functions like in c++? I am coming from c++ world, so pardon my ignorance.

Comment: @animageofmine Scala compiler can try to inline methods. There is [`@inline` attribute](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/inline.html) for this. But it can't inline functions because function call is a call to virtual `apply` method of a function object. JVM might devirtualise and inline such calls in some situations, but not in general.

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that the syntax `def even(i: Int): Boolean =` produces a different result than `def even: Int => Boolean =` ? That is to say, the double-arrow notation is NOT just syntactic sugar, but actually means something different to the compiler?

Comment: @bjmc: `def even: Int => Boolean` means `def even: Function2[Int, Boolean]`. It's almost like `def even(): Function2[Int, Boolean]`, but without empty argument list (0 argument lists vs 1 empty argument list).

Comment: @senia : def defFunc :  Int => Int  = _ + 1.   defFunc eq defFunc gives true. I tried this in scala repl

Comment: @Ashwin, jvm implementation details. Try ```def defFunc: Int => Int = { val i = uril.Random.nextInt; _ + i }```

Comment: I think this article gives a better answer of the subtle differences: https://alvinalexander.com/scala/fp-book-diffs-val-def-scala-functions

Comment: Actaully from your example I see `even eq even == true` in my scala shell

Comment: @KanagaveluSugumar it's a java 8 optimization. For some lambdas it can use the same object for multiple method calls. See next example with `Random` - eq returns false on any jvm version.

Comment: This is a great answer! I like the examples you provide to differentiate them

Comment: @Kaushik the first example is broken due to java 8+ optimisation (`eq` is true in both cases). I can fix it, but it will make the code more difficult.

Comment: Hi. Scala rookie here. I understand how val is evaluated when defined, but what happens when the function accepts a parameter? Doesn't that imply that it evaluates when called? What would be the difference with def in this case?

Comment: @JeroSquartini in case of `val x: (...) => R = ...` function is not evaluated. The function creation is evaluated. Function itself is just an object with `apply` method.

Answer (score 24):

Consider this:

```
scala> def even: (Int => Boolean) = {
             println("def"); 
             (x => x % 2 == 0)
       }
even: Int => Boolean

scala> val even2: (Int => Boolean) = {
             println("val");
             (x => x % 2 == 0)
       }
val //gets printed while declaration. line-4
even2: Int => Boolean = <function1>

scala> even(1)
def
res9: Boolean = false

scala> even2(1)
res10: Boolean = false
```

Do you see the difference? In short:

**def**: For every call to `even`, it calls the body of the `even` method again. But with `even2` i.e. **val**, the function is initialized only once while declaration (and hence it prints `val` at line 4 and never again) and the same output is used each time it accessed. For example try doing this:

```
scala> import scala.util.Random
import scala.util.Random

scala> val x = { Random.nextInt }
x: Int = -1307706866

scala> x
res0: Int = -1307706866

scala> x
res1: Int = -1307706866
```

When `x` is initialized, the value returned by `Random.nextInt` is set as the final value of `x`. Next time `x` is used again, it will always return the same value.

You can also lazily initialize `x`. i.e. first time it is used it is initialized and not while declaration. For example:

```
scala> lazy val y = { Random.nextInt }
y: Int = <lazy>

scala> y
res4: Int = 323930673

scala> y
res5: Int = 323930673
```

Comment: I think your explanation may imply something you don't intend.  Try calling `even2` twice, once with `1` and once with  `2`.  You will get different answers in each call.  So, while the `println` is not executed in subsequent calls you don't get the same *result* from different calls to `even2`.  As to why the `println` is not executed again, that is a different question.

Comment: that is actually very interesting. It is like in the case of val i.e. even2, the val is evaluated to a parameterized value. so yes with a val you the evaluation of the function, its value. The println is not part of the evaluated value. It is part of the evaluation but not the evaluated value. The trick here is that the evaluated value is actually a parametarized value, that depend of some input. smart thing

Comment: @melston exactly! that's what I understood, so why doesn't the println get executed again while the output changed ?

Comment: @a.u.r what is returned by even2 is actually a function (the parenthesized expression at the end of the definition of even2).  That function is actually called with the parameter you pass to even2 each time you invoke it.

Answer (score 6):

See this:

```
  var x = 2 // using var as I need to change it to 3 later
  val sq = x*x // evaluates right now
  x = 3 // no effect! sq is already evaluated
  println(sq)
```

Surprisingly, this will print 4 and not 9! val (even var) is evaluated immediately and assigned.
Now change val to def.. it will print 9! Def is a function call.. it will evaluate each time it is called.

Answer (score 1):

val i.e. "sq" is by Scala definition is fixed. It is evaluated right at the time of declaration, you can't change later. In other examples, where even2 also val, but it declared with function signature i.e. "(Int => Boolean)", so it is not Int type. It is a function and it's value is set by following expression

```
   {
         println("val");
         (x => x % 2 == 0)
   }
```

As per Scala val property, you can't assign another function to even2, same rule as sq.

About why calling eval2 val function not printing "val" again and again ?

Orig code:

```
val even2: (Int => Boolean) = {
             println("val");
             (x => x % 2 == 0)
       }
```

We know, in Scala last statement of above kind of expression (inside { .. }) is actually return to the left hand side. So you end up setting even2 to "x => x % 2 == 0" function, which matches with the type you declared for even2 val type i.e. (Int => Boolean), so compiler is happy. Now even2 only points to "(x => x % 2 == 0)" function (not any other statement before i.e. println("val") etc. Invoking event2 with different parameters will actually invoke "(x => x % 2 == 0)" code, as only that is saved with event2.

```
scala> even2(2)
res7: Boolean = true

scala> even2(3)
res8: Boolean = false
```

Just to clarify this more, following is different version of the code.

```
scala> val even2: (Int => Boolean) = {
     |              println("val");
     |              (x => { 
     |               println("inside final fn")
     |               x % 2 == 0
     |             })
     |        }
```

What will happen ? here we see "inside final fn" printed again and again, when you call even2().

```
scala> even2(3)
inside final fn
res9: Boolean = false

scala> even2(2)
inside final fn
res10: Boolean = true

scala>
```

Answer (score 1):

Executing a definition such as `def x = e` will not evaluate the expression e. In- stead e is evaluated whenever x is invoked.

Alternatively, Scala offers a value definition 
`val x = e`,which does evaluate the right-hand-side as part of the evaluation of the definition. 
If x is then used subsequently, it is immediately replaced by the pre-computed value of e, so that the expression need not be evaluated again.

Answer (score 0):

also, Val is a by value evaluation. Which means the right-hand side expression is evaluated during definition. Where Def is by name evaluation. It will not evaluate until it's used.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above helpful replies, my findings are:

```
def test1: Int => Int = {
x => x
}
--test1: test1[] => Int => Int

def test2(): Int => Int = {
x => x+1
}
--test2: test2[]() => Int => Int

def test3(): Int = 4
--test3: test3[]() => Int
```

The above shows that “def” is a method (with zero argument parameters) that returns another function "Int => Int” when invoked.

The conversion of methods to functions is well explained here: https://tpolecat.github.io/2014/06/09/methods-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

In REPL,

```
scala> def even: Int => Boolean = { _% 2 == 0 }
even: Int => Boolean

scala> val even: Int => Boolean = { _% 2 == 0 }
even: Int => Boolean = $$Lambda$1157/1017502292@57a0aeb8
```

def means `call-by-name`, evaluated on demand

val means `call-by-value`, evaluated while initialization

Comment: With a question this old, and with so many answers already submitted, it is often helpful to explain how your answer differs from, or adds to, the information provided in the existing answers.

Answer (score 0):

Note: There are different types of functions in Scala: abstract, concrete, anonymous, high order, pure, impure etc...

**Explaining val function:**

A val function in Scala is a complete object. There are traits in Scala to represent functions with various numbers of arguments: Function0, Function1, Function2, etc. As an instance of a class that implements one of these traits, a function object has methods. One of these methods is the apply method, which contains the code that implements the body of the function.

When we create a variable whose value is a function object and we then reference that variable followed by parentheses, that gets converted into a call to the apply method of the function object.

**Explaining Method i.e def:**

Methods in Scala are not values, but functions are.

A Scala method, as in Java, is a part of a class. It has a name, a signature, optionally some annotations, and some bytecode.

The implementation of a method is an ordered sequence of statements that produces a value that must be compatible with its return type.