# Practical difference between def f(x: Int) = x+1 and val f = (x: Int) => x+1 in Scala

Tags: function, scala, syntax, definition

I'm new to Scala and I'm having a problem understanding this. Why are there two syntaxes for the same concept, and none of them more efficient or shorter at that (merely from a typing standpoint, maybe they differ in behavior - which is what I'm asking).

In Go the analogues have a practical difference - you can't forward-reference the lambda assigned to a variable, but you can reference a named function from anywhere. Scala blends these two if I understand it correctly: you can forward-reference any variable (please correct me if I'm wrong).

---

Please note that this question is not a duplicate of [What is the difference between “def” and “val” to define a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18887264/what-is-the-difference-between-def-and-val-to-define-a-function).

I know that `def` evaluates the expression after `=` each time it is referenced/called, and `val` only once. But this is different because the expression in the `val` definition evaluates to a function.

---

It is also not a duplicate of [Functions vs methods in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839537/functions-vs-methods-in-scala).

This question concerns the syntax of Scala, and is not asking about the difference between functions and methods directly. Even though the answers may be similar in content, it's still valuable to have this exact point cleared up on this site.

Comment: Scala is somewhat constrained by targeting the JVM. Methods are native there while functions are not, hence the Scala compiler has, in a sense, more work to do to realize first-class functions than it does simple JVM methods. And it is not strictly true to say neither is more efficient than the other. There are various overheads for true functions in Scala that do not exist for mere methods.

Comment: I know that `def`ined functions are implemented as methods, and function literals as objects with an `apply` method. But if they can be used practically interchangeably is what I was asking. But I guess that answers the part about there being two separate syntaxes...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Functions vs methods in Scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839537/functions-vs-methods-in-scala)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are three main differences (that I know of):

#### 1. Internal Representation

Function expressions (aka anonymous functions or lambdas) are represented in the generated bytecode as instances of any of the `Function` traits. This means that function expressions are also objects. Method definitions, on the other hand, are first class citizens on the JVM and have a special bytecode representation. How this impacts performance is hard to tell without profiling.

#### 2. Reference Syntax

References to functions and methods have different syntaxes. You can't just say `foo` when you want to send the reference of a method as an argument to some other part of your code. You'll have to say `foo _`. With functions you can just say `foo` and things will work as intended. The syntax `foo _` is effectively wrapping the call to `foo` inside an anonymous function.

#### 3. Generics Support

Methods support type parametrization, functions do not. For example, there's no way to express the following using a function value:

```
def identity[A](a: A): A = a
```

The closest would be this, but it loses the type information:

```
val identity = (a: Any) => a
```

Comment: what about def foo(x: Int): Int = x + 1.  List(1,2,3).map(foo).  There is no need for foo(_)?

Comment: @AndrewCassidy No, this is called eta-expansion and scalar will do this automatically (convert method into first-class function)

Comment: @AlexIv could you edit the answer to provide examples when eta-expansion is needed and where it can be used?

Answer (score 0):

As an extension to Ionut's first point, it may be worth taking a quick look at http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.Function1.

From my understanding, an instance of a function as you described (ie.
`val f = (x: Int) => x + 1`) extends the `Function1` class.  The implications of this are that an instance of a function consumes more memory than defining a method.  Methods are innate to the JVM, hence they can be determined at compile time.  The obvious cost of a Function is its memory consumption, but with it come added benefits such as composition with other Function objects.

If I understand correctly, the reason `def`s and lambdas can work together is because the Function class has a self-type `(T1) ⇒ R` which is implied by its `apply()` method https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.8/src/library/scala/Function1.scala#L36.  (At least I THINK that's what going on, please correct me if I'm wrong).  This is all just my own speculation, however.  There's certain to be some extra compiler magic taking place underneath to allow method and function interoperability.