# what's the difference between def and var/val for an anonymous function

Tags: scala

I'm confused about anonymous function definitions as following:

```
var plusOne = (x:Int)=>x+1
// or val plusOne=(x:Int)=>x+1
println(plusOne(2))
```

Or

```
def plusOne = (x:Int)=>x+1
println(plusOne(2))
```

What's the difference please in `var`/`val` and `def` for a function name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Practical difference between def f(x: Int) = x+1 and val f = (x: Int) => x+1 in Scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22354396/practical-difference-between-def-fx-int-x1-and-val-f-x-int-x1-in)

Comment: This has nothing to with functions. The difference between `var`, `val`, and `def` has nothing to do with their type. `var` and `val` are fields ("variables", if you will), `def` is a method. It doesn't matter what they return.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- **val** declares an "immutable variable or rather symbol" that doesn't allow reassignment, right hand side of the assignment is evaluated immediately
- **var** declares a "mutable variable" that allows reassignments later to the symbol, right hand side of the assignment is evaluated immediately just like val
- **def** declares an "immutable symbol" that doesn't allow reassignment, right hand side is evaluated lazily, i.e. whenever that symbol is referenced later in the code

Example -

```
var plusOneVar = (x:Int)=>x+1
val plusOneVal = (x:Int)=>x+1
def plusOneDef = (x:Int)=>x+1

plusOneVar = (x:Int)=>x+2 // Reassignment to var is valid
plusOneVal = (x:Int)=>x+2 // Compile time error, reassignment to val
plusOneDef = (x:Int)=>x+2 // Compile time error, reassignment to val
```

Because you are looking at an example with functions, it is hard to understand. Let's try to understand it with simple variables.

```
var symbolVar = 100        // line 1
val symbolVal = symbolVar  // line 2
def symbolDef = symbolVar  // line 3

println(symbolVar)  // prints 100
println(symbolVal)  // prints 100
println(symbolDef)  // prints 100 - no surprise yet

symbolVar = symbolVar + 1

println(symbolVal)  // still prints 100 which was evaluated and assigned on line 2
println(symbolDef)  // prints 101 as symbolDef is a def and it depends on symbolVar, line 3 is evaluated again
```

Answer (score 2):

`var plusOne` can be reassigned. `val plusOne` cannot be reassigned. Both are evaluated once. `def plusOne` is evaluated each time it is called

Comment: well, var plusOne changed to val plusOne, what's difference with def please :)

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand, could you please give a simple example code. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You might want to make it more clear what exactly is evaluated once vs each time.

Answer (score 1):

Note also with `val` (or `var`) one instance of the function is created and is used for any number of invocations to that function, whereas with `def` a new instance of the function is created for each invocation. Yet, for

```
def f (i:Int) = i+1
f: (i: Int)Int
```

note

```
val g = f _
g: Int => Int = <function1>
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be clear from the Class File Disassembler results using `javap`. Save the following code as `Test.scala`

```
class Test {
  val fVal: Int => Int = x => x + 1
  var fVar: Int => Int = x => x + 1
  def fDef(x: Int): Int = { x + 1 }
}
```

and do `scalac Test.scala; javap Test` will show

```
Compiled from "Test.scala"
public class Test {
  public scala.Function1<java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object> fVal();
  public scala.Function1<java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object> fVar();
  public void fVar_$eq(scala.Function1<java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object>);
  public int fDef(int);
  public Test();
}
```

As is shown in the results above, `val` and `fVar` are represented as methods that return a Function1 object. The difference is `fVar` has an additional "setter". While `fDef` is like normal Java method.