# What this meas in scala?

Tags: function, scala

I am new to scala, today I saw a function definition I could not understand:

```
def f(x: Int): Int = x
val func = (x: Int, y: Int, z: Int) => f(x)
```

So in Scala, what is the syntax of defining `func` ?  To me, `func` is just a function accepts three parameters: `func: (Int, Int, Int) => Int = <function3>` . Why not just define `func` as

```
def func(x: Int, y: Int, z: Int): Int = f(x)
```

Is this for the reason of efficiency ? Since we just need to evaluate a val once.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18887264/what-is-the-difference-between-def-and-val-to-define-a-function See the last paragraph of the accepted response.

Answer (score -1):

`func` is defined as a value that holds a function with that signature, and it is initialized with such a function. At some time in the future, in a class method, you could provide a different function. It would be invoked as `func(1,2,3)` and return the result based on the function that was actually assigned to `func` at that point in time.

This provides an alternative to overriding a method in a subclass. For instance, you might have a state machine implementation that needed to respond to inputs in a different fashion, depending upon the state; this would be feasible way to respond appropriately by changing the value of the receiving function.

Comment: `func` is a `val`. You can't re-assign it.

Comment: I can only plead premature senility. You are correct.