# Scala: separate states of count variable inside returned method

Tags: scala, closures, constants

Scala newbie trying to implement a method named "counter" whose method signature is below.

The method should be a stateless function so that when it is invoked with integer n, it returns a stateful function. This stateful function should return n when it is first called, then n + 1, then n + 2, etc.

The counters must be independent such that running counter(1) twice yields two functions that do not interfere with each other's state.

Below is what I have so far:

```
val counter : Int => () => Int = {
   // Complete definition below.
   var count = 0

   n: Int => () => {
       var returnVal = n + count
       count = count + 1
       returnVal
   }
}
```

An example of how counter is called:

```
  assert ({ 
     val k1 : () => Int = counter (1)
     val k2 : () => Int = counter (2)
     val r1 : Int = k1 ()
     val r2 : Int = k1 ()
     val r3 : Int = k2 ()
     val r4 : Int = k2 ()
     val r5 : Int = k2 ()
     val r6 : Int = k1 ()
     (r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6)
  } === (1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3)
  )
```

When running the assert, my implementation of counter returns (1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 6).

I believe this is due to k1 and k2 both pointing to the same count variable. However, I can't figure out how I would provide k1 and k2 their own separate count variable so that they "do not interfere with each other's state", as per the requirements.

Am I on the right track? Any guidance would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, check out [the difference between `def` and `val`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18887341/1159255). The TL;DR of it is that `val` will only evaluate once, so you can't really depend on a count-holding variable if you define it in `counter` before you get to the function you want to return.

To make it clearer, I added parenthesis to make the pattern matching more obvious and broke apart that line because we needed to capture the parameter that was passed-in to `counter` and store it in the closure for the anonymous function we are returning.

```
val counter : Int => () => Int = {
  (n: Int) => {
    var count = n

    () => {
      val returnVal = count
      count = count + 1
      returnVal
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Not that it matters a lot here, but I would make `returnVal` a `val`.

Comment: Good call @Jasper-M.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the keyword from `val` to `def` for the *counter* method you are defining:

```
def counter : Int => () => Int = {
   // Complete definition below.
   var count = 0

   n: Int => () => {
       var returnVal = n + count
       count = count + 1
       returnVal
   }
}
```

Because with `val`, the *count* variable is only defined once which happens when you define the *counter* method, so later on all the closures will share this variable; with `def` method, the *count* variable will be redefined every time you call *counter(n)*.

---

It's easier to see this if you add a println after the `var count = 0` line:

```
scala> val counter : Int => () => Int = {
          // Complete definition below.
          var count = 0
          println(count)

          n: Int => () => {
              var returnVal = n + count
              count = count + 1
              returnVal
          }
       }

0                                           // 0 is printed here
counter: Int => (() => Int) = <function1>

scala> val k1 = counter(1)                  // nothing prints here
k1: () => Int = <function0>

scala> val k2 = counter(2)                  // nothing prints here
k2: () => Int = <function0>
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes more sense. Unfortunately, I have to keep the val keyword as per the guidelines of the assignment.