# Scala complication. Variable reassignment

Tags: scala

I'm trying to understand how Scala works. So I typed this code.

```
var name = "eMmanuel"
val n = name.exists(_.isUpper)

name = "book"
```

Just looking at it, in my mind, I expect `n` to be `true`, I compile this and `n: Boolean = true`, which is understandable. But in the console I see something strange.

```
name: String = book
n: Boolean = true
name: String = book
```

After compilation, first line of results from console tells me `name: String = book` now, if `name` is now `String = book` why is `n: Boolean = true`? Shouldn't this be `false`? because after all, it's showing `name: String = book`which obviously has no capital letter in it!

Comment: Are you actually re-evaluating the second line? Because the result stored in n is not lazy, it will only be calculated once.

Answer (score 5):

*I'm assuming `name = book` is actually `name = "book"`.*

`n` will have an unchanged value **because it is a `val`**. **A `val` gets only evaluated once, on assignment** (there are also `lazy val`s that are evaluated on first dereference). **See e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437373/use-of-def-val-and-var-in-scala)** for more information.

In your specific case, it looks like you wanted `n` to be evaluated each time, **which means you need to declare `n` as a `def`**, i.e.:

```
def n = name.exists(_.isUpper)
```

This will create a no-argument method, evaluated every time you invoke `n`.