# Significance of val or var in immutable objects

Tags: scala

Does **val or var** make difference in **immutable objects** like lists or tuple?

```
scala> val ab = List(1,2,3)
ab: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> var ab = List(1,2,3)
ab: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

I am beginner in scala.

Comment: A `var` can reference new/different mutable or immutable objects at different times in the program.  A `val` cannot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between a var and val definition in Scala?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791408/what-is-the-difference-between-a-var-and-val-definition-in-scala)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be confusing two different aspects of immutability.  The local variable `ab` refers to some object in memory, in this case a `List`.  When you declare `ab` as a `val` you are instructing the compiler that `ab` will always refer to the same object.  Because `List` is immutable, its contents will never change, but a `var` referring to it might be reassigned to some other `List`.

```
scala> import scala.collection.mutable.MutableList
import scala.collection.mutable.MutableList

scala> val a = List(1,2,3,4)
a: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> val b = MutableList(1,2,3,4)
b: scala.collection.mutable.MutableList[Int] = MutableList(1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> var c = List(1,2,3,4)
c: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Here, `a` is a `val` containing an immutable data structure.  `a` refers to `List(1,2,3,4)` and will always do so.

The `val b` refers to a `MutableList`.  We can change the internal contents of the `MutableList` but we cannot assign `b` to a different `MutableList`.

```
scala> b += 5
res6: b.type = MutableList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> b = MutableList(2,3,5,7)
<console>:12: error: reassignment to val
       b = MutableList(2,3,5,7)
         ^
```

With `var c` we have a variable that refers to an immutable data structure `List` but that can be reassigned to a different `List`.

```
scala> c = c :+ 5
c: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Note that the `:+` operator (unlike the `+=` operator above) does not change the `List` referred to by `c`.  Instead it create a copy of the `List` with the element `5` appended.  Because `c` was declared a `var` we can then assign this *new* list to `c`.

Answer (score 2):

It's not really relevant whether the object that `ab` points to is mutable. `val` means that you cannot in the future assign ab to another value, while `var` allows it.

Try repeating the assignment in each case and see what happens:

```
scala> val ab = List(1,2,3)
ab: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
scala> ab = List(1,2,3)
reassignment to val; not found: value ab

scala> var ab = List(1,2,3)
ab: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
scala> ab = List(1,2,3)
ab: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score -2):

It's a question of style.

In Scala using a `val` is generally preferred to using a `var` as in (functional) programming immutability makes it easier to reason about a program.

So if you can get what you want without resorting to var it is the way to go.

A typical application of a var would be if you want to use an immutable data structure and update it benifitting of structural sharing.

```
var data = List.empty[String] // var is importan here
def addToData(s: String) : Unit = { data = s :: data }
```

The same could be achieved by using a mutable datastructure

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

val data = ArrayBuffer.empty[String]
data += "Hello" // this function is here from the beginning
```

For an in depth discussion look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/4440614/344116 .