# Scala Function Definitions and Performance

Tags: scala

I can define a function or a method in Scala as below:

```
def myMethod: Boolean = true
```

or

```
val myBoolVal = () => true
```

Which one is preferred any why? Is defining a myMethod has compiler benefits? Any suggestions?

Comment: The first expression defines a method, the second expression defines an immutable pointer to a lambda, which evaluates to `true` and takes no arguments. For sanity, I would stick to the first definition, if you truly are interested in this, check the byte code the two expressions compile to.

Comment: I don't know who down voted this question. This is definitely not a silly question!

Comment: They are also called differently, `myMethod //> true` and `myBoolVal() //> true`. Just two completely different entities. Relative equivalent of the first would be `val myBooleanVal = true`. Unless you need a lambda I would stick with `def` or `val myBooleanVal = true`.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but while not silly, it's also a duplicate... See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529184/difference-between-method-and-function-in-scala and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437373/use-of-def-val-and-var-in-scala?rq=1 (which is linked to from this question - it was probably suggested to you when you wrote the question?)