# swap two variable by scala language

Tags: scala, if-statement, scala-collections, scalatest

```
val numClasses = 5
val categoricalFeaturesInfo = Map[Int, Int]()
val impurity = "gini"
val maxDepth = 0
val maxBins = 32
val greaccuracy = 0
for( maxDepth <- 0 to 30){
val model = DecisionTree.trainClassifier(trainData, numClasses,  categoricalFeaturesInfo, impurity, maxDepth, maxBins)
val metrics = getMetrics(model, cvData)
val accuracy = metrics.precision
if (accuracy >  greaccuracy){
greaccuracy =  accuracy
}
}
println("Accuracy = "+greaccuracy)
```

please any help
 error: reassignment to val
               greaccuracy =  accuracy
                           ^

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use of def, val, and var in scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437373/use-of-def-val-and-var-in-scala)

Answer (score 2):

val are immutable variables, once set you cannot change them. That's by designed. var on other hand you can change them.