# Does Java 10 provide a val keyword? If not, why not?

Tags: java, type-inference, java-10

Java 10 brings a C#-like `var` keyword for [local type-inference](https://developer.oracle.com/java/jdk-10-local-variable-type-inference).

But does Java 10 also provide a `val` keyword, as is [found in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437373/use-of-def-val-and-var-in-scala)?

`val` would work like `var` but the binding would be `final`.

```
var x = "Hello, world. ";
x = "abc"; // allowed

val y = "Hello, world. ";
y = "abc"; // forbidden
```

If it does not, is there a reason that this is the case?

Comment: Not sure a "yes/no" question would be a good question here. But I don't see why it would include both `var` and `val` for the "same feature".

Comment: Probably not: https://blog.codefx.org/java/java-10-var-type-inference/#Why-Is-There-No-valconstlet  So, it'll be `final var`

Comment: @AxelH `val` and `var` have different meanings, so they are not the same feature

Comment: Both do type-inference, one is final, the other is not. This is what I call the same. Is `String` and `final String` are different type for you ?

Comment: In the case of `String` then `var` is equivalent to `String` and `val` would be equivalent to `final String`. They are related, but not the same.

Comment: Did you ***[try it out](https://tio.run/##y0osS9TNSsn@/7@gNCknM1khOSexuFjBNzEzT6GaixMqWFySWAKkyvIzUxRygVIawSVFmXnp0bEKiUXpxZoglZzBlcUlqbl6@aUlegVAyZKcPA0lj9ScnHwdhfD8opwURSVNay7OWq7a//8B)?***

Comment: I think this question can be salvaged by turning this into a "why" question instead of "yes/no" (the accepted answer remains valid).

Comment: @PixelElephant fair point; question updated

Comment: @sdgfsdh Why not you try Kotlin code in your java project. Kotlin provides `val` keyword. You can use Kotlin in Java code and vice versa. You can find the sample code used [here](https://webfirmframework.github.io) which uses `val` keyword.

Comment: Side note, if you still want to use val anyway, you can always use Lombok

Answer (score 57, accepted):

There is no `val` in Java 10, as stated in [JEP 286: Local-Variable Type Inference](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/286):

> **Syntax Choices**
>
> There was a diversity of opinions on syntax. The two main degrees of freedom here are what keywords to use (var, auto, etc), and whether to have a separate new form for immutable locals (val, let). We considered the following syntactic options:
>
> - var x = expr only (like C#)
> - var, plus val for immutable locals (like Scala, Kotlin)
> - var, plus let for immutable locals (like Swift)
> - auto x = expr (like C++)
> - const x = expr (already a reserved word)
> - final x = expr (already a reserved word)
> - let x = expr
> - def x = expr (like Groovy)
> - x := expr (like Go)
>
> After gathering substantial input, var was clearly preferred over the Groovy, C++, or Go approaches. There was a substantial diversity of opinion over a second syntactic form for immutable locals (val, let); this would be a tradeoff of additional ceremony for additional capture of design intent. **In the end, we chose to support only `var`**. Some details on the rationale can be found [here](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/platform-jep-discuss/2016-December/000066.html).

And here's the main reasoning:

> I know this is the part people really care about :)   After considering 
>   the pros and cons at length, there appears to be an obvious winner -- 
>   var-only.  Reasons for this include:
>
> - While it was not the most popular choice in the survey, it was 
>     clearly the choice that the most people were OK with.  Many hated 
>     var/val; others hated var/let.  Almost no one hated var-only.
> - Experience with C# -- which has var only -- has shown that this is a 
>     reasonable solution in Java-like languages.  There is no groundswell of 
>     demand for "val" in C#.
> - The desire to reduce the ceremony of immutability is certainly 
>     well-taken, but in this case is pushing on the wrong end of the lever. 
>     Where we need help for immutability is with fields, not with locals. But 
>     var/val doesn't apply to fields, and it almost certainly never will.
> - If the incremental overhead of getting mutability control over that 
>     of type inference were zero, there might be a stronger case, but it was 
>     clear that many people found two different leading keywords to be a 
>     distraction that kept their eyes from quickly settling on the important 
>     stuff.  If variable names are more important than types, they're more 
>     important than mutability modifiers too.

([Source](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/platform-jep-discuss/2016-December/000066.html))

Comment: "_[..] Some details on the rationale can be found [here](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/platform-jep-discuss/2016-December/000066.html)_"

Comment: "_Immutability is important, but in reality, local variables are the least 
important place where we need more help making things immutable.  Local variables are immune to data races; most locals are effectively final anyway.  Where we need more help in encouraging immutability is *fields* -- but applying type inference there would be foolish._"

Comment: Interesting, is it possible to enhance final for this approaches? Namely, to support usage like this: final varName = new Object(). Isn't it logical that if you put final inside methods then you mean final var? Just, maybe silly, fantasy.

Comment: @Eran I think it was definitely overlooked that there's WAY less cases where we want variables compared to constants in most programs. It would have been much more beneficial to support `val` over `var` IMO and people would also stop declaring variables where constants would suffice...

Comment: For example, since JavaScript added `const`, almost no one uses `let` unless required. Furthermore, the argument that 2 keywords would be too distracting is absurd. They could read through all these explicit type declarations and suddently they would get too distracted by `var/val` or `var/let` to understand the code? To better support mutability over immutability is as absurd as allowing references to be `null` by default...

Answer (score 10):

Because there is `final var` for that in Java. If we had `val` too, there would be two things that mean the same. This is not good. There should be only one way to express a particular thing.

Comment: `var` also does not seem to express anything that was not possible before. Both `var` and `val` just make things shorter.

Comment: `var` does express something that was impossible before: the real type of an anonymous class. For example, it's now possible to do `var foo = new Object() { int i = 1; };` and access `foo.i` _without reflection_. Of course, this is only useful within the body of a method, since you can only return the supertype.

Comment: @MichealHill Actually it was possible before. E.g. you can write `t(new Object() { int i = 1; }).i` in Java 8, where `t` is defined as `public static <T> T t(T t) { return t; }`.

Comment: This is a highly opinionated answer with no clear basis. There are lots of ways to express a loop: `for(;;)`, `for (x : y)`, `.forEach`, `do..while`...

Comment: @LucasRoss These are quite different flavors of a `for` loop.

Comment: an if statement and a switch statement can also express the exact same thing, but having both gives the flexibility to write clearer and terser code. val would also help with that.

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov what's the advantage of `t(new Object() { int i = 1; }).i` over `(new Object() { int i = 1; }).i`?

Comment: There's alway Lombok for someone who disagree.  Lombok val takes Java closer to Kotlin and allows to leverage legacy code base but modernise it for better readability, safety, and semi-forma proof of execution path.

Comment: Then add `val` and get rid of `final var`.

Having to add those 6 extra characters every time is a mess. So people don't bother, and just declare them as `var`, and then you lose the quick cognitive shortcut for knowing that the value won't be changed anywhere in the code.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to use "val", that is, "final var", you always can to use [Lombok's val](https://projectlombok.org/features/val).

Comment: Not "always"... Lombok is a hack:
https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/issues/2131
https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/issues/2652

Comment: Lombok doesnt play nice with other JVM languages (in a mixed mode project)

Comment: So basically we need a library to use val. got it.

Comment: @WindyFields: Since v1.18.22 Lombok no longer uses a big [hack](https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/pull/2928) for Java 10+.