# Android Studio cannot resolve symbol text turns red

Tags: java, android-studio

I know that if you write something wrong in code you get a red underline.

My problem is that the whole word turns red and I get the error

> "Cannot resolve symbol '(and then whatever the code is)'"

when I hold the mouse over it.

I have downloaded Java just to see if it were the problem. I also followed [this tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/build-your-first-android-app/#1) on how to download Android studio.

The program I made is from [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EOfCEhWq8sg&t=436s) on Youtube.

The `path` text in the top gets a red underline.

I don't know if it helps but i'm using Windows 10 and Android Studio 3.3

Here you can see my code turning red:
[image]

Comment: Seems you are writing Kotlin code inside a Java file

Comment: @elbraulio:  Because this is an issue with an IDE, images are actually *kinda* okay in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're writing Kotlin in a Java file.  Because of this, your IDE doesn't understand the symbols you're using to define variables.  Note that even more recent versions of Java [don't support `val`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49426958/1079354), which is why I presume you're attempting to use Kotlin here.

Your choice:  write your code in either Kotlin or Java, but not both at the same time.