# Cannot resolve Error In Spark when filter records with two where condition

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

SPARK 1.6, SCALA, MAVEN

i have created a dataframe from RDD and trying to filter out all records where cola= null or empty string and colb = 2 or 3.

i tried something like this.

```
df.filter(WHERE $"COLA isnull AND COLB =02 & 03")

But unfortunately getting error as "cannot resolve 'COLA isnull where COLB =02 & 03'
```

Please help

Comment: You need to use an `in` list: `...AND colb isin ('02','03')`  If colb is a string (02), you need the single quotes.

Comment: @Andrew: is it something like this you are saying. df.filter($"cola in(null or '') where colb ='01' & '05'")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    You can try as below:

    df.filter($"COLA".isNull && $"COLB".isin("02","03"))
```

Refer for more details: [Convert SQL Case Statement into Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58085414/convert-sql-case-statement-into-spark/58102827#58102827)

Answer (score 1):

Messed up the syntax in my comment above.

`$"cola".isNull && $"colb".isin("02","03")`

That syntax works for me (2.1 and 2.4).  If 1.6 doesn't like it, try it this way:

```
val foo = List("H","D")
df.filter($"COLA".isNull && $"colb".isin(foo_*))
```

Comment: Many Thanks, but it seems some syntax error is there, trying to fix it

Comment: df.filter($"COLA" isnull && $"COLB".isin('01','03'))
 
Error:(86, 66) unclosed character literal

Comment: The only way I can reproduce that exact error is if I don't close the double quotes around one of the column names. You do need to use double quotes for your filter values (`isin("02","03")`), but I get a different error if I use single quotes.

Comment: sorry but getting error as df.filter($"cola" isnull && $"colb".isin("01","03")) Error:(86, 68) ';' expected but ')' found.

Comment: Argh, it's `.isNull`, see edit.  For me, it's case sensitive.  isNull works, isnull does not.